# How I can sort data using jquery.tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table,

```
http://jsfiddle.net/fisker228/L8bwW/32/
```

I use plugin tablesorter to sort the data. But I want to sort only lines marked the border and lines below should consistently go for the lines with borders. If you already prepared for such a widget sorting?
If I click here `http://joxi.ru/v29JeZDtj4peAG` , I want to sort as follows: `http://joxi.ru/E2pk5oLcjv47mY` . I tried to use a plugin "Row statics", but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I initially posted an answer to another question...

I think what you could do is use more than one tbody to separate the content. Maybe something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/L8bwW/33/)):

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tfoot>...</tfoot>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No, I need to sort the contrary only bordered rows

Comment: sort on you demo I can use staticrow plugin, but I don't need it